# How can I host VMs on my Ubuntu Server for remote access within my LAN?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vnc, remote, qemu

I've read a bunch about KVM, installed it and then successfully create a VM inside it using [this guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm).

Now I would like to be able to access it from my other computers (Windows and Ubuntu) within my LAN.

I noticed that in Virtual Machine Manager, I can add a connection (presumably to be used from a client?). So I would probably need to configure a server/daemon... where should I start?

Then, how would I access it from my clients (windows/ubuntu).

Comment: If you are starting from zero, consider using VirtualBox which has a much more user-friendly and simpler user interface that gives you more guidance. Also, you never mentioned what you intend to do with your VMs (please edit your question accordingly).

Comment: For network access from the outside, you'll need to configure a _network bridge_, and you'll want to give your VMs a fixed IP and a hostname in your network router. If you are using a DSL home router, most of them can bind a fixed IP and a hostname to a MAC address (which the VM or the VM manager will tell you). If all that means nothing to you, you are in for a rocky start. ;-)

Comment: By setting a network bridge, wouldnt my VMs be part of my home LAN? I'd rather keep them under the hypervisor's NAT for security, to separate it from my LAN since I want to use my VM for penetration testing among other things... (legally of course with hackthebox.eu)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get what I wanted. I'm not sure it's the best way to do it but it seems to work very well.

1. I setup SSH access to my Ubuntu server (with keys) and enabled X11 forwarding ([this guide helped me through this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server)).
2. I setup KVM using the guide mentioned in my original post ([here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm))
3. I installed Putty and Xming on my Windows client ([guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575703/13232555)).
4. From my client, with Putty, I connect to my Ubuntu Server then launch virt-manager which then opens a XMing GUI where I can run  & launch my VM in another XMing window (see picture of end state).

[image: Xming windows on my Windows client]